# Turning off visibility of layer using ArcObjects Java?

Tags: arcobjects, layers, java, table-of-contents

I'm making a geoprocessing tool with ArcObjects Java (`IBasicGeoprocessingTool`) and I need to make a layer not visible. I managed to get this layer as `IFeatureLayer` and I get an access to the map or activeView.
I tried that:

```
featureLayer.setVisible(false);
((IActiveView)map).refresh();
```

After that, the layer is not visible but it remains checked in the table of contents. Does anyone know how to access to the TOC or MapControl to uncheck it please?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to refresh the TOC, you can do this through the IMXDocument interface using [UpdateContents()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IMxDocument_UpdateContents.htm) method.

Comment: OK, that's exactly what I need, but do you know how to get the mxdocument or application from the BaseGeoprocessingTool (or gpUtilities object)?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool like this once so I could hot key. Here is the Dock code I wrote for it.

```
public partial class ToggleVisibility_Dock : UserControl
{
    #region User Control

    public ToggleVisibility_Dock(object hook)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Hook = hook;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Host object of the dockable window
    /// </summary>
    private object Hook
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation class of the dockable window add-in. It is responsible for 
    /// creating and disposing the user interface class of the dockable window.
    /// </summary>
    public class AddinImpl : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.DockableWindow
    {
        private ToggleVisibility_Dock m_windowUI;

        public AddinImpl()
        {
        }

        internal ToggleVisibility_Dock UI
        {
            get { return m_windowUI; }
        }

        protected override IntPtr OnCreateChild()
        {
            m_windowUI = new ToggleVisibility_Dock(this.Hook);
            return m_windowUI.Handle;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (m_windowUI != null)
                m_windowUI.Dispose(disposing);

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region Field(s)

    public IApplication _application;
    private IMap _map;
    private IContentsView _contentsView;
    private IMxDocument _mxdocument;
    IActiveView _activeview;
    private Classes.Utilities _utilities;
    private const string MB_TITLE = "Toggle Visible Layers";

    #endregion

    #region Event(s)

    private void ToggleVisibility_Dock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void btnInitialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void cboLayer1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IFeatureLayer layer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer1.Text);
        if (layer.Visible == true)
        {
            lblLayer1.Text = "Visible";
            lblLayer1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            lblLayer1.Text = "Not Visible";
            lblLayer1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void cboLayer2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IFeatureLayer layer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer2.Text);
        if (layer.Visible == true)
        {
            lblLayer2.Text = "Visible";
            lblLayer2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            lblLayer2.Text = "Not Visible";
            lblLayer2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void cboLayer3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IFeatureLayer layer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer3.Text);
        if (layer.Visible == true)
        {
            lblLayer3.Text = "Visible";
            lblLayer3.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            lblLayer3.Text = "Not Visible";
            lblLayer3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void cboLayer4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IFeatureLayer layer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer4.Text);
        if (layer.Visible == true)
        {
            lblLayer4.Text = "Visible";
            lblLayer4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }           
        else        
        {           
            lblLayer4.Text = "Not Visible";
            lblLayer4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Method(s)

    private void Initialize()
    {
        CheckInitialRequirments();
    }

    private bool CheckInitialRequirments()
    {
        _application = this.Hook as IApplication;
        _mxdocument = (IMxDocument)_application.Document;
        _map = _mxdocument.FocusMap;
        _contentsView = _mxdocument.get_ContentsView(0); // The List Item Order in TOC
        _activeview =  _mxdocument.ActivatedView;

        _utilities = new Classes.Utilities(_map);

        cboLayer1.Items.Clear();
        cboLayer2.Items.Clear();
        cboLayer3.Items.Clear();
        cboLayer4.Items.Clear();

        cboLayer1.Items.AddRange(_utilities.FeatureLayers().ToArray());
        cboLayer2.Items.AddRange(_utilities.FeatureLayers().ToArray());
        cboLayer3.Items.AddRange(_utilities.FeatureLayers().ToArray());
        cboLayer4.Items.AddRange(_utilities.FeatureLayers().ToArray());

        if (this.cboLayer1.Items.Count > 0) this.cboLayer1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        if (this.cboLayer2.Items.Count > 1) this.cboLayer2.SelectedIndex = 1;
        if (this.cboLayer3.Items.Count > 2) this.cboLayer3.SelectedIndex = 2;
        if (this.cboLayer4.Items.Count > 3) this.cboLayer4.SelectedIndex = 3;

        return (cboLayer1.Items.Count != 0) ? true : false; // Make sure there is at least one layer in TOC
    }

    private bool CheckToggleRequirments(int layer_count)
    {
        IFeatureLayer featurelayer;
        try
        {
            if (cboLayer1.Items.Count < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Add feature layers", MB_TITLE, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return false;
            }
            switch (layer_count)
            {
                case 1:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer1.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.FeatureClass == null)
                        return false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer2.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.FeatureClass == null)
                        return false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer3.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.FeatureClass == null)
                        return false;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer4.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.FeatureClass == null)
                        return false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void ToggleVisibility(int layer_count)
    {
        IFeatureLayer featurelayer = null;
        if (CheckToggleRequirments(layer_count))
        {
            switch (layer_count)
            {
                case 1:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer1.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.Visible == true) { featurelayer.Visible = false; }
                    else { featurelayer.Visible = true; }
                    //cboLayer1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer2.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.Visible == true) { featurelayer.Visible = false; }
                    else { featurelayer.Visible = true; }
                    //cboLayer2_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer3.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.Visible == true) { featurelayer.Visible = false; }
                    else { featurelayer.Visible = true; }
                    //cboLayer3_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    featurelayer = _utilities.FeatureLayer(cboLayer4.Text);
                    if (featurelayer.Visible == true) { featurelayer.Visible = false; }
                    else { featurelayer.Visible = true; }
                    //cboLayer4_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
                    break;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            cboLayer1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
            cboLayer2_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
            cboLayer3_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
            cboLayer4_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
        catch (Exception) { } // "Meaningless" error catching needed
        _contentsView.Refresh(null);
        _activeview.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeography, featurelayer, null);
    }

    #endregion
}
```